# Pivot using 2 tables (probably dynamic)

Tags: sql, pivot

This might require dynamic pivot, but I'm not entirely sure
I have been tasked to generate the following:

```
Table1: Donor
         DonorID     CustomerPaymentID
         --------    ------------------
         DonorID1    CustomerPaymentID1
         DonorID1    CustomerPaymentID2 
         DonorID2    CustomerPaymentID3
```

Table2: Customer

```
 CustomerID     CustomerName    CustomerActiveDate     CustomerPaymentID
 ----------     -------------   ------------------     -----------------
 CustomerID1    CustomerName1   CustomerActiveDate1    CustomerPaymentID1
 CustomerID2    CustomerName2   CustomerActiveDate2    CustomerPaymentID2
 CustomerID3    CustomerName3   CustomerActiveDate3    CustomerPaymentID3
```

Retrieve data as

```
DonorID     CustomerIDNo1   CustomerNameNo1     CustomerActiveDateNo1     CustomerPaymentIDNo1   CustomerIDNo2   CustomerNameNo2     CustomerActiveDateNo2     CustomerPaymentIDNo2
--------    -------------   ---------------     ---------------------     --------------------   -------------   ---------------     ---------------------     --------------------
DonorID1    CustomerID1     CustomerName1       CustomerActiveDate1       CustomerPaymentID1     CustomerID2     CustomerName2       CustomerActiveDate2       CustomerPaymentID2
DonorID2    CustomerID3     CustomerName3       CustomerActiveDate3       CustomerPaymentID3     NULL            NULL                NULL                      NULL
```

In other words bring all the customer data for each donor.

The maximum number of customers per donors is 5.
I'm using a Microsoft SQL database.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of customers per donor?  That is, do you know what columns are in your result set?  Also, tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with temp as (
   select d.donor_id
     ,c.cust_id
     ,c.cust_name
     ,c.cust_active
    ,c.cust_payment_id
    ,row_number() over(partition by d.donor_id order by c.cust_id) as donor_cust_order
   from donor d, cust c
   where d.cust_payment_id = c.cust_payment_id)
select donor_id,
max(case when donor_cust_order = 1 then cust_id end) as cust_id_1,
max(case when donor_cust_order = 1 then cust_name end) as cust_name_1 ,
max(case when donor_cust_order = 1 then cust_active end) as cust_active_1,
max(case when donor_cust_order = 1 then cust_payment_id end) as cust_payment_id_1,
max(case when donor_cust_order = 2 then cust_id end) as cust_id_2,
max(case when donor_cust_order = 2 then cust_name end) as cust_name_2,
max(case when donor_cust_order = 2 then cust_active end) as cust_active_2,
max(case when donor_cust_order = 2 then cust_payment_id end) as cust_payment_id_2,
max(case when donor_cust_order = 3 then cust_id end) as cust_id_3,
max(case when donor_cust_order = 3 then cust_name end) as cust_name_3,
max(case when donor_cust_order = 3 then cust_active end) as cust_active_3,
max(case when donor_cust_order = 3 then cust_payment_id end) as cust_payment_id_3
from temp
group by donor_id
order by 1;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much. I was looking to fix my problem with pivot, but this works like a charm. You are awesome. Thanks